# How to use pageref with expl3?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, expl3

I think there is something I have not understood about global variables. The following MWE does not work to display the total page number in the footer :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,refcount} % For this example
\pagestyle{fancy}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page}}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_gset:Nn { NV }

\int_new:N \g_total_page_int
\int_gset:NV \g_total_page_int {\getpagerefnumber{last-page}}

\cfoot{
    Total~:~\int_use:N \g_total_page_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

But this one does :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,refcount} % For this example
\pagestyle{fancy}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page}}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn { NV }

\int_new:N \l_total_page_int

\cfoot{
    \int_set:NV \l_total_page_int {\getpagerefnumber{last-page}}
    Total~:~\int_use:N \l_total_page_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

The first way seems to be correct and prevents from setting multiple times (lg)_total_page_int. But why doesn't it work ?

Comment: `\int_set:Nn` is what you need, I guess. Your usage of `\int_set:NV` is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the file containing the reference information is not read until `\begin{document}`. You need to defer setting the variable until then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,refcount} % For this example
\pagestyle{fancy}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page}}

\int_new:N \g_total_page_int
\AtBeginDocument{
  \int_gset:Nn \g_total_page_int {\getpagerefnumber{last-page}}
}

\cfoot{
    Total~:~\int_use:N \g_total_page_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

Note that you should have `:Nn` as the signature and not `:NV` because `{\macro{something}}` is not a variable.